# Android 4.0 does not recognize null

Tags: android

I have custom gridview adapter in the getview method I am checking String for NULL or Empty, but the condition does not seem to work as it prints string "null" to the textview below is the code

```
if(!ThisAttendee.AllocatedTable.equals(null) && ThisAttendee.AllocatedTable.toLowerCase().trim() != "null" && !ThisAttendee.AllocatedTable.trim().isEmpty())
        {
            ((TextView)(gridviewitem.findViewById(R.id.tv_attendeetable))).setText("Table: "+ThisAttendee.AllocatedTable);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.equals()` instead of `==` to check if the String is `"null"`,
and `==` instead of `equals()` to check for `null`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/767379/675383

Comment: I have changed it to `if(ThisAttendee.AllocatedTable != null && !ThisAttendee.AllocatedTable.toLowerCase().trim().equals("null") && !ThisAttendee.AllocatedTable.trim().equals(""))
  {
   ((TextView)(gridviewitem.findViewById(R.id.tv_attendeetable))).setText("Table: "+ThisAttendee.AllocatedTable);
  }` now it prints text table only I tried what you suggested above but same result

Comment: actually the text table was coming from the xml where I was hardcoding textview to text to be visible in the design mode ;)